# Azure oauth with external authentication service

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I'm developing an infrastructure that allows different applications in the organization to produce and consume events from/to azure event hub.
Each application has a backing AD application and service principal with Event Sender/Reciever Role assignments.
We are using kafka client to produce/consume events to the hub and oauth for authentication.

When the client connects, it sends the client id and secret to Azure AD and receives a token to auth with.
We need to authenticate the client not only with azure AD, but also with our organization authentication service.
Is there a way to configure azure oauth to call some external service (with some headers or some parameters) for authentication, before returning the token to the client?

[image]

Any reply will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible using Azure AD only. You will need an API that can authenticate your clients against both.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Can you please elaborate? i dont want my users to be able to connect to the event hub with ms AD client id and secret only.

Comment: @yaarix you will have to develop a custom API that validates your user against both Azure AD and the External Auth Service.

Comment: That i understand. The problem is how to force each call from a kafka client to use that api. We don't want any client to be able to authenticate itself with azure ad only. So developing an api is not enough, we need azure to force all clients to authenticate using that api

Comment: @yaarix you need to contact kafka support about that.

Comment: We are using Events hub with a kafka client, authentication is made using azure ad (since we must grant a Data Reader/Receiver Roles to the applications). so not sure kafka will help me with that